# $f$-divergence: $D_f(P || Q) = 0 \iff P = Q$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convex-analysis, expected-value

Let $f$ be a function such that:

(1) $f$ is convex.

(2) $f(1) = 0$

(3): $f : \mathbb{R}_{> 0} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$

(4): $f$ is strictly convex around $1$ which means $$f(kx + (1 - k)y) < k f(x) + (1 - k) f(y) \, \,\, \,\, \,\, \, $$

$$\forall \, k \in (0, 1) \, \, \, \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0} \text{ such that } kx + (1 - k)y = 1 \text{ and } x \ne 1$$

Now let $P, Q$ be probability measures on $\mathcal X$ and other necessary conditions
[found on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence#Definition) .
\begin{align*}
D_f(P || Q) &= \mathbb{E}_Q f \left(\frac{dP}{dQ} \right) \\
&\geq f \left( \mathbb{E}_Q \frac{dP}{dQ} \right)\\
&= f \left( \int_\mathcal{X}  dP \right)\\
&= f(1)\\
&= 0   
\end{align*}

I want to prove $D_f(P || Q) = 0 \iff P = Q$

$P = Q$ $\implies $ $D_f(P || Q) = 0 $ is easy.

Assume $D_f(P || Q) = 0$. Then, from above we know $$\mathbb{E}_Q f \left(\frac{dP}{dQ} \right) = f \left( \mathbb{E}_Q \frac{dP}{dQ} \right)  $$

How to complete the proof to show $P = Q$?

Comment: The statement needs a conditions on $f$ - strict convexity at $1$ (this is necessary to avoid things like $f = x-1$, for which the result doesn't hold). You can argue this by unpacking the argument of Jensen's inequality. Basically, if strictly convex at $1$, then there's some witnessing subgradient $a$ such that at every $y \neq 1,$ $f(y) > a(y-1).$ Then consider $\mathbb{E}[ f(dP/dQ) \mathbf{1}\{dP/dQ \neq 1\}]$ to get a strict lower bound of $0$ on $D$ so long as $Q ( dP/dQ \neq 1) > 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: Not sure what etiquette is here. The answer below (beyond the first dashed line) was given prior to the addition of condition (4) above, suggested by @stochasticboy321. For my own sake, I wrote out his reasoning more fully beyond the second dashed line. I added below the third dashed line a slightly more complicated counterexample which may be used to sketch the necessity of strict convexity at 1.

---

This is not true in general. As a very simple example, take $f = 0$, which gives you that the divergence between any two measures is 0.

It would be interesting to know if there are simple conditions on $f$ which would guarantee this property. For KL divergence, Hellinger distance, and total variation (all examples of f-divergences), this equivalence holds and you can find proofs just by tracing through Wikipedia.

---

As suggested, if we have strict convexity of $f$ at 1, then we have that $f(y) > a(y-1)$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$. We then note: 
$$\mathbb{E}_Q\left[f\left(\frac{dP}{dQ}\right)\right] = \mathbb{E}_Q\left[f\left(\frac{dP}{dQ}\right) \mathbb{1}_{\{dP/dQ \neq 1\}}\right] > \mathbb{E}_Q\left[a\left(\frac{dP}{dQ} - 1 \right)\mathbb{1}_{\{dP/dQ \neq 1\}}\right].$$
The second strict inequality only holds if $Q(\{dP/dQ \neq 1\}) > 0$, which is equivalent to $P \neq Q$. This last term is equal to 0:
$$\mathbb{E}_Q\left[a\left(\frac{dP}{dQ} - 1 \right)\mathbb{1}_{\{dP/dQ \neq 1\}}\right]=a\mathbb{E}_Q\left[\left(\frac{dP}{dQ} - 1 \right)\right]=a(1-1)=0.$$

Thanks for the suggestion @stochasticboy321!

---

It also seems to me that strict convexity at 1 is not only sufficient, but necessary. Lack of strict convexity means that $f$ is linear in some neighborhood of 1, and it is not difficult to construct counterexamples then.

For an explicit one, consider $f(y) = y-1$, and $dQ = dx$ and $dP = 2x \, dx$ on the unit interval. Then we have that:
$$\mathbb{E}_Q\left[f\left(\frac{dP}{dQ}\right)\right] = \int^1_0 2x-1 \, dx = 0,$$
despite the fact that $dP \neq dQ$. It's not too difficult to see how some version of this simple example can be "plugged in" locally for any $f$ that is locally linear near 1.

Comment: We only have $f(y) > a (y - 1)$ for all $y \ne 1$, right?

Comment: Do you have a proof for "$f$ strictly convex at 1" $\implies$ "there exists a $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(y) > a (y - 1)$ for all $y \ne 1$"? If I am not mistaken, the function $f(x) := \max(1 - x, 0)^2 + \iota_{[0, \infty)}(x)$ is strictly convex at 1, but there is no such $a$ (We only have non-strict inequality for $a = 0$.)

Comment: I think my above counterexample is correct because of the following definition (A.11) and proposition (A.7) from Liese and Vadja's "Convex Statistical Distances":

Comment: **Defn.** A continuous convex function $f \colon [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R \cup \{ \infty \}$ with $f|_{(0, \infty)}$ being finite (in their notation $f \in K[0, \infty)]$) is strictly convex at 1 if and only if $f(1) < p f(u_1) + (1 - p) f(u_2)$ for all $p \in (0, 1)$ and all $u_1, u_2 \in [0, \infty)$ with $p u_1 + (1 - p) u_2 = 1$ and so that we don't have $u_1 = u_2 = 1$. **Prop.** A function $f$ as above is strictly convex at $1$ if and only if there exists a $c \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(u) > c (u - 1)$ for all $u$ from *at least* one of the intervals $(0, 1)$ and $(1, \infty)$.